# Why would varnish.service suddenly change its port? (From 80 to 6081)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, gunicorn, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have a WordPress site with gunicorn and varnish running on an AWS instance.

This morning, the website gave a "502 Bad Gateway nginx" error.

Upon investigation, it looks like the `varnish.service` port was:

`ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m`

According to some notes, the port needs to be `80` and not `6081`. Changing the port to `80` fixed the nginx error.

This issue seems to happen about once a year where the `varnish.service` port suddenly changes by itself and someone has to manually change the port back to `80`.

So my question is - why would `varnish.service` suddenly change its port? As far as I know, there were no updates or changes anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what file you're editing.

Make sure you're editing `/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service`. If that file isn't there, just run the following command:

```
sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service /etc/systemd/system/
```

When you're done editing the port, just run the following 2 commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart
```

See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/installing-varnish-ubuntu/#systemd-configuration for a detailed tutorial.

Comment: Thanks - the file `varnish.service` file is there. It's just that out of the blue one day, the port changed from `6081` to `80`. Reverting it back to `6081` fixes the problem - but why would it have randomly changed to `80` in the first place?